# ‘Concern of’ vs. ‘concern about’

Tags: idioms, prepositions

> Commercial builders downplayed ______ a bust in the superheated housing market.

1) The concern of
2) Concerns about

The answer is number 2, but why does number 1 not work?

Comment: Because _a concern of a bust_ would indicate that _the bust_ has some concern, but that is not the case. _He listened to the concerns of the people_ means that the people were concerned about some things. In this case the concerns are _about_ a bust.

Comment: @oerkelens it should be the *answer*, friend! :)

Comment: @MaulikV: I was a bit lazy, but Araucaria worded my comment as a perfectly elaborated answer, I think :)

Comment: @oerkelens Coming from you, that's praise indeed! ;)

Answer (score 7):

> Commercial builders downplayed ______ a bust in the superheated housing market.

> 1. the concern of
> 2. concerns about

We often use the preposition *of* to show possession or ownership.

- a friend *of* Bob's.
- the legs *of* the giraffe
- one concern *of* mine

Here Bob has a friend, the giraffe has legs, and I have a concern. This last thing means that I am worried. I have the emotion.

We use the preposition *about* to show the topic of an idea or feeling:

- worried *about* the problem
- thinking *about* my sister
- excited *about* my date

Here the topic of my worry is the problem,  my sister is the topic of my thoughts, my date is the topic of my excitement. Notice that the problem does not have the worry, my sister is not having the thoughts, and my date may not have any feelings of excitement!

In the Original Poster's example we do not know who had the concerns. But we do know the concerns related to the bust in the market. We therefore need to say "concerns about the bust". If we said "concerns of the bust", this would mean that the financial bust was worried! This is impossible!

Hope this is helpful!

Comment: +1 for the subtle humbling of your own dating capabilities! :-D